# Ruby Regular expression not matching properly

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to creat a RegEx to find words that contains any vowel.
so far i have tried this

```
/(.*?\S[aeiou].*?[\s|\.])/i
```

but i have not used RegEx much so its not working properly.
for example if i input "test is 1234 and sky fly test1234"
it should match test , is, and, test1234 but showing
test, is,1234 and
if put something else then different output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can also do something like:

```
"test is 1234 and sky fly test1234".split.find_all { |a| a =~ /[aeiou]/ }
# => ["test", "is", "and", "test1234"]
```

Comment: I knew this but i wanted a RegExp. Thanks

Comment: sure, this was just an alternative way to achieve what you wanted. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the below regex.

```
\S*[aeiou]\S*
```

`\S*` matches zero or more non-space characters.

or

```
\w*[aeiou]\w*
```

Comment: It worked, is there anyway i can exclude the word containg any number like "test1234" ? i guess w means all except those \n \r etc

Comment: `\w` means word character.ie a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ . To exclude numbers, you could use `[a-zA-Z]*[aeiou][a-zA-Z]*`

Comment: try `(?<!\S)[^\d\s]*[aeiou][^\d\s]*(?!\S)`

Answer (score 1):

It will solve:

```
\b\w*[aeiou]+\w*\b
```

https://www.debuggex.com/r/O-fU394iC5ErcSs7

---

or you can substitute `\w` by `\S`

```
\b\S*[aeiou]+\S*\b
```

https://www.debuggex.com/r/RNE6Y6q1q5yPJbe-

---

`\b` - a word boundary

`\w` - same as `[_a-zA-Z0-9]`

`\S` - a non-whitespace character

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\b\w*[aeiou]\w*\b
```

`\b` denotes a word boundry, so this regexp matches word bounty, zero or more letters, a vowel, zero or more letters and another word boundry